# How to use "BETWEEN" in CASE statement

Tags: sql, case, between

I have created a scalar function that should convert the mark of the student to a letter, I used the CASE & Between to switch values as follows:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [GetLetterGrade] 
(
    @avg decimal ,
    @isCommented bit
)
RETURNS Char(50)
AS
BEGIN
return case WHEN @isCommented = 0   THEN    
            CASE
            when @avg between 97 And 100 THEN '01'
            when @avg Between  93 And 97 THEN '02'
            when @avg Between  90 And 93 THEN '03'
            when @avg Between  87 And 90 THEN '04'
            when @avg Between  83 And 87 THEN '05'
......
```

The function is jumping from one case to another on 96.5 instead of 97 and on 92.5 instead of  93 and so on, any idea?

[[image: Sample]]

Please help

Comment: did you try using decimals? i.e. `when @avg between 97.0 and 100.0 THEN '01'`

Comment: Thank you, Yes, this made a change but did not entirely solve the problem. now, instead of switching to on the 0.5 it is doing that on 0.999999.
the average 96.999999 is returning the first case '01'

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement . (An expression returns a value.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), the expression `expr BETWEEN min AND max` is equivalent to `(expr <= max AND expr >= min)` only when all three arguments are the same type. Otherwise type conversion is applied to all arguments. It would be during this conversion that roundoff errors would occur.

For your case, I would suggest rounding DOWN, using `FLOOR`.

`when FLOOR(@avg) between 97 And 100 THEN '01'`

Answer (score 0):

The default scale for a decimal is 0, so the rounding is taking place in the function call.

In addition, you don't need `between` because the `case` conditions are ordered.  So,  I would recommend trying:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [GetLetterGrade] (
    @avg decimal(10, 2) ,
    @isCommented bit
) RETURNS Char(50)
AS BEGIN
    return (case when @isCommented = 0     
                 then (case when @avg >= 97 then '01'
                            when @avg >= 93 then '02'
                            when @avg >= 90 then '03'
                            when @avg >= 87 then '04'
                            when @avg >= 83 then '05'
             ......
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not work, it is still switching on the 0.5

Comment: @HayanAlMamoun . . . Even with the explicit scale and precision in the function definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
return case WHEN @isCommented = 0   
                THEN  (  
                CASE
                when @avg >=97 And @avg <=100 THEN '01'
                when @avg >=93 And @avg <97 THEN '02'
                when @avg >= 90 And @avg < 93 THEN '03'
                when @avg >=  87 And @avg < 90 THEN '04'
                when @avg >=  83 And @avg < 87 THEN '05'
```